# Move home to partition or resize home to fit partition

Tags: centos, lvm, partitioning

I've two disks in my PC. My /home is in the /dev/sda3 so it's on sda1. Then I have another disk formated and mounted as /data in /dev/sdb1. I want to move /home to /data or delete data complety and resize /home to fit all the space in data. My partition system use LVM and it's CentOS 6.3. Which solution is best and what I need to do in order to get this done?

**EDIT:**
This is my `df` output:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             29696992   2402600  25785836   9% /
tmpfs                   928504         0    928504   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2               495844     83245    386999  18% /boot
/dev/sdb1            307665016    233508 291803016   1% /data
/dev/sda3              5124192    489980   4373912  11% /home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to completely remove /data and /home is a lvm.. you can just grow /dev/sda3 by using /dev/sdb1

If you post a `df` output I can help more with the answer.

**edit**

So you don't use LVM at all. So your best bet to get it working right now is something like the following if you don't care about anything in data

```
umount /data
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
mount -a
mv /home/* /data/
umount /data
umount /home
```

Edit /etc/fstab and remove the /dev/sdb1 line and change /dev/sda3 with /dev/sdb1. Then mount

```
mount -a
```

/home should then be using /dev/sdb1 and have all your files in it.

Comment: Done, edited the main entry and added the `df` command output