# Resizing LVM partitions on a live CentOS 6 server

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, lvm

I currently have the following partitions:

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_server/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_server/lv_home' [1.76 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_server/lv_swap' [5.86 GiB] inherit
```

I would like to reduce the `lv_home` partition which is almost empty and increase the `lv_root` partion as it is getting close to full. I have a full backup but would like to do this on a live server which I do not have the ability to use a live CD on.

I would like to resize the partitions and reboot and get everything running again fairly quickly. Is there a moderately safe way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is to avoid having to use your backups.  If `lv_home` is really "almost empty",

- you could shrink that (resize the filesystem, then shrink the logical volume), and
- use the freed-up space for a temporary volume to copy `lv_home` to.
- *Then*, the existing `lv_home` is empty, and you can demolish it, extend `lv_root` as needed, and
- finally (if `lv_home` is *really* that small, initially), move the temporary volume's contents back into the part of the empty space that you don't need for `lv_root`, and combine that with the temporary space.

The suggested ordering assumes that the underlying disk partitions are in the same order, of course.  LVM is not suited to shifting partitions up and down (as some offline disk partitioning tools may do).

Now - the OP's question did not mention whether the underlying filesystem(s) all reside on one physical disk, and whether their disk partitions are in the same order. If they all reside on one physical disk, the question comes up whether this is partitioned with MBR (a maximum of four physical partitions) or GPT (128) -- see for example *[What's the difference between MBR and GPT?](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/233291-32-what-difference)* .  In the former case, OP may have to create an extended partition as a basis for the resized `lv_home` partition.

LVM is essentially three layers: physical, volumes and logical.  To keep things tidy, it's nice to have the physical disks adjacent.  But LVM does not require that.  One could shrink `lv_home` (and its filesystem and physical partition) in one step, and then create a new physical partition in the space on the end, adding that partition  to the volume group corresponding to `lv_root` and then running [`resize2fs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) to extend the filesystem.  Resizing up has a lot of existing practice; going down far less so -- until recently the documentation had caveats explaining that you could trash your filesystem with the tool.

These may be helpful:

- [Resizing LVM Partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/879181/resizing-lvm-partitions?rq=1)
- [Gparted cannot resize extended or LVM partition](https://superuser.com/questions/917988/gparted-cannot-resize-extended-or-lvm-partiton?rq=1)
- [Move home to partition or resize home to fit partition](https://superuser.com/questions/499240/move-home-to-partition-or-resize-home-to-fit-partition?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks and good ideas. In my case lv_home is 99% empty, 1.7TB free.

Comment: This method worked for me and it seems to be the safest way from what I can read. This answer was also very detailed and took into account other possible situations that may arise.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lvextended` command for change size of logical volume:

```
lvextend -l +4607 /dev/vg_home/LogVol01
resize2fs /dev/vg_home/LogVol01
```

I suggest reading up conceptually about [lvm resize and reduce on this site](http://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/).

Comment: OP seemed to already be aware of the basic tools.  The real problem seems to be how to move the starting point of `lv_home` to make room for extending `lv_root`.

Comment: Thomas we can easy do it lvextend can reduce with - and extended it with +

Comment: My goal is to keep all the data on all partitions after the resize is done. How does this method compare to the answer @ThomasDickey wrote in terms of possibly overwriting files on the partition I would be shrinking?